# sklearn LabelBinarizer choose which label (string) is the positive

Tags: scikit-learn

From my tests using sklearn 0.24.1 it seems that LabelBinarizer orders the strings in the data to be binarized and chooses the last value as "positive". For instance:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
print(lb.fit_transform(['a', 'd', 'd', 'a']))

lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
print(lb.fit_transform(['e', 'd', 'd', 'e']))
```

In the first case 'd' is chosen to be '1' and in the second one 'e' is chosen to be '1'. I haven't been able to find a parameter or a way to specify with string (e.g. 'a' in the first case or 'd' in the second) should be the '1'. I have even tried ChatGPT, which showed up weird things.

In any case, the following did the trick:

```
print(-1 * (lb.fit_transform(['e', 'd', 'd', 'e']) -1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of class labels is stored in `LabelBinarizer.classes_` attribute.

After `fit(X)`, it should be totally safe to re-order its elements if it doesn't agree with your requirements.

```py
from sklearn import preprocessing

import numpy

lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
print(lb.fit_transform(['a', 'd', 'd', 'a']))

# Take a look at the learned order
print(lb.classes_)

# Invert it
lb.classes_ = numpy.asarray(["d", "a"])

print(lb.transform(['a', 'd', 'd', 'a']))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with fixed classes, you can use `label_binarize()` instead:

```
print(preprocessing.label_binarize(['e', 'd', 'd', 'e'], classes = ['e', 'd']))
```

Worth noting this also allows for custom order label encoding if you apply `argmax()` to it.